# Problem with link editing

Tags: bug, links

In [How to implement date filters with operators like <= or >= in a JSON query string?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/98894/16495) user posted this link:

```
http://example.com/drupal/api(endpoint)/sampleview.json?field_invoice_date_value<='2013-12-31'&field_invoice_date_value>='2013-11-31'
```

He posted it without formatting, so it ended looking like this:

http://example.com/drupal/api(endpoint)/sampleview.json?field_invoice_date_value<='2013-12-31'&field_invoice_date_value>='2013-11-31'

Not good, right? So I tried to edit it into `[url](url)` format. **In preview it looks OK** (hit "edit" to see, just don't save), but in question, see:

http://example.com/drupal/api(endpoint)/sampleview.json?field_invoice_date_value<='2013-12-31'&field_invoice_date_value>='2013-11-31'

It seems there is no way to post this link as a link and keep it displayed properly. Or there is and I just don't know it?

---

If it's general issue, please consider migration to Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

That string isn't a valid URL, so it shouldn't be displayed as a link.

The editor is processing it correctly per the rules for a valid URL, so it stops as soon as it hits the `<` character

In such edge cases converting it to a code block as you did is the best course of action.

Comment: Well, the fact it's OK on preview and fails on normal view is a bug for me - even if the correct behavior would be to fail on preview.

Comment: Yep you're right that still does class as a bug. Think I've seen something similar on MSO I'll try to dig it out